# Yii RBAC make Users update profile by himself

Tags: mongodb, yii, authorization, yii-extensions, rbac

I'm trying to do this with [mongodbauthmanager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mongodbauthmanager). I'm  follow step by step in `Usage` section but finally i'm getting **PHP warning: Illegal offset type**. I had posted this question at [Yii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mongodbauthmanager/#c12707) before clone to SO:

Please tell me what is wrong?

**1// Config**

```
 'authManager'=>array(
    'class'         =>'CMongoDbAuthManager',
    'showErrors'    => true,
  ),
```

**2// Create auth items in db**

```
$auth = new CMongoDbAuthManager();

$bizRule = 'return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["User"]->_id;';
$auth->createTask('updateSelf', 'update own information', $bizRule);
//I had tried with $auth->createOperation() but they has the same error
$role = $auth->createRole('user');
$role->addChild('updateSelf');

$auth->save();
```

and here is result in db
[result in db http://i.minus.com/iIpXoBlDxaEfo.png](http://i.minus.com/iIpXoBlDxaEfo.png)

**3// Checking access in controller ** - *UPDATE CODE AND ERROR*

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $params = array('User'=>$model);
        if (!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', Yii::app()->user->id,$params) )
        {
            throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not authorized to perform this action');
        }
//another statement ...
}
```

**4// Getting error:**

**Fatal error** : Cannot use object of type MongoId as array in F:\Data\03. Lab\www\yii\framework\web\auth\CAuthManager.php(150) : **eval()'d** code on line 1

## RESOLVED PROBLEM

Base-on the answer of `@Willem Renzema`, I resolve my problem. Now, I update here and hope it useful for someone have this error.

**0// First, config authManager with defaultRoles**

```
   'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CMongoDbAuthManager',
        'showErrors' => true,
        'defaultRoles'=> array('user'),//important, this line help we don't need assign role for every user manually
    ),
```

**1// Fix save id in UserIdentity class**

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    //...
    public function authenticate()
    {
         //...
         $this->_id = (string)$user->_id;//force $this save _id by string, not MongoId object
         //...
    }
    //...
}
```

**2// Fix $bizrule in authe items**
($bizrule will run by `eval()` in `checkAccess`)

```
//use _id as string, not MongoId object
$bizRule = 'return Yii::app()->user->id==(string)$params["User"]->_id;';
```

**3// And user checkAccess to authorization**

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
        /**
         * @var User $model
         */
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $params = array('User'=>$model);
        if (!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', $params) )
        {
            throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not authorized to perform this action');
        }
        //...
}
```

4// Done, now we can use checkAccess :D

Comment: Look at the signature of `checkAccess`, specifically the second argument.

Comment: Yes, i'm put it Yii::app()->user->id and get `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoId as array in \www\yii\framework\web\auth\CAuthManager.php(150) : eval()'d code on line 1`. 
<br />

Comment: So what does your updated code look like? From the error message it seems like you changed `$params` as well...

Comment: i change one line:
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', Yii::app()->user->id, $params)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why that problem could happen. It's failing during `eval` of your `bizRule`, so maybe you can do `var_dump($params)` inside it or something like that. (Update your post with the latest code and error, so other people can see the status.)

Comment: Thank for you care. I have been updated latest code. now I'm try var_dump as you say.

Comment: What version of Yii are you using?

Comment: I´m using yii 1.1.13, in my question, I posted and changed some errors in every time I try to solved. Please view revision for detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your original use of `checkAccess` was correct. Using `Yii::app()->user->checkAccess()` you are using the following definition:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail

Now, `CWebUser`'s implementation of `checkAccess` calls `CPHPAuthManager`'s implementation, which is where you encountered your problem with an illegal offset type.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpAuthManager#checkAccess-detail

An `Illegal offset type` means you are attempting to access an array element by specifying its key (also known as: offset) with a value that doesn't work as a key. This could be another array, an object, null, or possibly something else.

Your stack trace posted on the extensions page reveals that the following line gives the problem:

```
if(isset($this->_assignments[$userId][$itemName]))
```

So we have two possibilities for the illegal offset: `$userId` and `$itemName`.

Since `$itemName` is clearly a string, the problem must be with `$userId`.

(As a side note, the fact that your stack trace revealed surrounding code of this error also revealed that, at least for `CPHPAuthManager`, you are using a version of Yii that is prior to 1.1.11. Observe that lines 73 and 74 of https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.11/framework/web/auth/CPhpAuthManager.php do not exist in your file's code.)

At this point I would have guessed that the problem is that the specified user is not logged in, and so `Yii::app()->user->id` is returning `null`. However, the new error you encountered when placing `Yii::app()->user->id` as the 2nd parameter of `checkAccess` reveals something else.

Since the 2nd parameter is in fact what should be the `$params` array that appears in your `bizRule`. Based on the error message, this means that `Yii::app()->user->id` is returning a `mondoId` type object.

I was unfamiliar with this type of object, so looked it up:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php

Long story short, you need to force `Yii::app()->user->id` to return the string value equivalent of this `mondoId` object. This likely set in your `UserIdentity` class in the `components` folder. To force it to be a string, simply place `(string)` to force a type conversion.

Example:

```
$this->_id = (string)$User->_id;
```

Your exact code will vary, based on what is in your `UserIdentity` class.

Then, restore your `checkAccess` to the signature you had before, and it should eliminate the `Illegal offset error` you encountered originally.

Note however that I have not used this extension, and while performing the following actions should fix this issue, it may cause new issues if the extension relies on the fact that `Yii::app()->user->id` is a `mondoId` object, and not a string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Summary, `checkAccess` need $userId is a string, and I put here and object (MongoId). I have been completed this task.